# BASH команда для получения имени n-ой директории в пути

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash

**Нужно узнать имя каталога находящегося выше текущего, потом еще выше и т.д. в BASH**

Например есть директория:

**/home/Ochen/Glupiy/Vopros**

Мне надо получить имя: **Glupiy**

Потом получить имя еще более верхней DIR: **Ochen**

И т.д.

Если для текущей директории (**Vopros**) моя BASH команда

`pwd | grep -o '[^/]*$'`

представляла из себя квадратные колеса, то командой для директории, что выше (**Glupiy**) можно обзываться

`pwd | grep -o [^/]* | sed -e '$!{h;d;}' -e x`

Для директории, что еще выше я уже ничего не придумал :)

Мне надо как то составить такую **BASH** команду, которой я бы смог дергать имя текущей, верхней, что еще выше и т.д., директории.

Если нельзя составить более менее универсальную команду, то киньте в меня хотя бы командой для получения имени DIR на 2 уровня выше.

Например для: **/home/Ochen/Glupiy/Vopros**

получить имя: **Ochen**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда для получения имени DIR на **N** уровней выше, считая рабочую:

```
pwd|tr / "\n"|tail -N|head -1
```

В Вашем примере **/home/Ochen/Glupiy/Vopros** :

N=1 => Vopros

N=2 => Glupiy
и т. д.

А в варианте

```
pwd|tr / "\n"|sed 's/^$/\//'|tail -N|head -1
```

не потеряется корневая директория

N=5 => /

Поместите команду

```
pwd|tr / "\n"|sed 's/^$/\//'|tail -"$1"|head -1
```

в файл, сделайте исполняемым и вызывайте с аргументом **N**

Чтобы работало с каталогами, внутри имен которых перевод строки,

применяем

```
pwd|tr "\n" "\0"|tr / "\n"|sed 's/^$/\//'|tail -N|head -1|tr "\0" "\n"
```

Comment: Ха-ха, что будем делать с каталогами, внутри имён которых перевод строки? `dirname` & `basename` лучше использовать.

Comment: Согласен, спасибо! Но легко решается - поправил ответ. NULL гарантированно не может присутствовать в имени.

Answer (score 5):

можно воспользоваться программами `basename` и `dirname`:

- `basename` выделяет из переданного пути последнюю часть
- `dirname` «отрезает» от переданного пути последнюю часть, оставляя всё остальное

---

```
$ cd /home/Ochen/Glupiy/Vopros
$ basename $(pwd)
Vopros
$ dirname $(pwd)
/home/Ochen/Glupiy
$ basename $(dirname $(pwd))
Glupiy
$ basename $(dirname $(dirname $(pwd)))
Ochen
```

Comment: Вот реально правильный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

`pwd | cut -d '/' -f 3`

`-d` - указывает, что сейчас будем указывать разделитель, `'/'` - экранированный разделитель, `-f` - какой по счёту разделитель выплёвывать. `-f 3` - как раз для твоего **Ochen**.

Comment: Хорошее решение, но оно не подходит, например если я здесь: **/home/x/y/z/folder** и вызову **pwd | cut -d '/' -f 6**, то получу folder, а если тут: **/home/x/y**, то получу ничего, мне же надо чтобы из любой директории одна и та же команда могла например вывести имя текущего каталога или того, что несколько повыше.
Т.е. чтобы получить например имя каталога выше текущего находясь в разных директориях на разных уровнях ваша команда уже не подойдет, придется ее менять для разных случаев.

Answer (score 3):

Например, можно так:

```
#/bin/bash
# echo N-th from the tail component of PATH ($2 argument)
# Usage: ./tn.sh N PATH

function getn {
    n=$(($# - $1))
    echo ${!n}
}

IFS=/
x=`getn $1 $2`
echo x=$x
```

Пример использования

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ pwd
/home/avp/hashcode
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./tn.sh 1 `/bin/pwd`
x=avp
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Comment: Вроде все так поставил, но выводятся только директории, что у вас в кавычках.

Comment: Вторым аргументом передавайте ту директорию, компонент которой хотите получить (и, естественно, уберите из echo текст `x=`, это там просто для иллюстрации). Для вывода только нужного компонента можете написать там в конце просто `getn $*`

Answer (score 2):

Например, так вы можете получить массив из каталогов, чтобы обращаться к ним по индексу:

```
IFS=/ read -r -a array <<<$(pwd)
```

Правда, нулевой элемент будет пустым, т. к. перед начальным `/` каталога нет. Но это ж не проблема?

Проверка:

```
[VladD@Tigger] [00:28:47] [/tmp/x/y/z]
{0,97}$> cat ./t.sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=/ read -r -a array <<<$(pwd)

idx=${#array[@]}-1
echo ${array[$idx]}

idx=${#array[@]}-2
echo ${array[$idx]}

idx=${#array[@]}-3
echo ${array[$idx]}

[VladD@Tigger] [00:29:01] [/tmp/x/y/z]
{0,98}$> pwd
/tmp/x/y/z

[VladD@Tigger] [00:29:06] [/tmp/x/y/z]
{0,99}$> ./t.sh
z
y
x
```

Comment: Вывод почти как от **pwd | grep -o [^/]***, только эта команда выводит уже весь список имен директорий, я просто не знаю как например  брать из этой команды последнюю или например пред пред последнюю строку. Просто хотелось бы обойтись без создания sh файлов, а запихнуть все в команду.